# 403 when fetching user.photoURL from onAuthStateChanged()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, svelte

In my server handle hook (SvelteKit) I have:

```js
const sessionCookie = event.cookies.get('__session')
event.locals.decodedIdToken = await adminAuth.verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie!)
event.locals.firebaseCustomToken = await adminAuth.createCustomToken(event.locals.decodedIdToken.uid)
```

In the front-end in my firebase.ts I have:

```js
export const auth = getAuth()
setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence)

// Custom token auth
export async function signIn(token: string): Promise<UserCredential | null> {
  return await signInWithCustomToken(auth, token)
}

// Irrelevant to this question I think, but here is how I'm getting the user credentials
export function authStore() {
  let unsubscribe: () => void

  if (!auth || !globalThis.window) {
    console.warn('Auth is not initialized or not in browser')
    const { subscribe } = writable(null)
    return { subscribe }
  }

  const { subscribe } = writable(auth?.currentUser ?? null, (set) => {
    unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      set(user)
    })

    return () => unsubscribe()
  })

  return { subscribe }
}

export const userCredentials = authStore()
```

And in my root layout I call the `signIn` function:

```js
export let data

onMount(() => {
  if (data.firebaseCustomToken) {
    signIn(data.firebaseCustomToken)
  }
})
```

And in one of my components when I try to load an image with the `user.photoURL` src, I'm getting 403 error. I can copy-paste the same URL in a new tab and it loads fine.

The decoded credentials from the server hook return the same URL. The authenticated user is using Google Auth.

What am I doing wrong?